# mysql moving average of N rows

Tags: mysql, select, moving-average

I have a simple MySQL table like below, used to compute MPG for a car.

```
+-------------+-------+---------+
| DATE        | MILES | GALLONS |
+-------------+-------+---------+
| JAN 25 1993 |  20.0 |    3.00 |
| FEB 07 1993 |  55.2 |    7.22 |
| MAR 11 1993 |  44.1 |    6.28 |
+-------------+-------+---------+
```

I can easily compute the Miles Per Gallon (MPG) for the car using a select statement, but because the MPG varies widely from fillup to fillup (i.e. you don't fill the exact same amount of gas each time), I would like to computer a 'MOVING AVERAGE' as well.  So for any row the MPG is MILES/GALLON for that row, and the MOVINGMPG is the SUM(MILES)/SUM(GALLONS) for the last N rows.  If less than N rows exist by that point, just SUM(MILES)/SUM(GALLONS) up to that point.

Is there a single SELECT statement that will fetch the rows with MPG and MOVINGMPG by substituting N into the select statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to return the specified resultset with a single SQL statement.

Unfortunately, MySQL does not support analytic functions, which would make for a fairly simple statement. Even though MySQL does not have syntax to support them, it is possible to emulate some analytic functions using  MySQL user variables.

One of the ways to achieve the specified result set (with a single SQL statement) is to use a JOIN operation, using a unique ascending integer value (rownum, derived by and assigned within the query) to each row.

For example:

```
SELECT q.rownum          AS rownum
     , q.date            AS latest_date
     , q.miles/q.gallons AS latest_mpg
     , COUNT(1)               AS cnt_rows
     , MIN(r.date)            AS earliest_date
     , SUM(r.miles)                AS rtot_miles
     , SUM(r.gallons)              AS rtot_gallons
     , SUM(r.miles)/SUM(r.gallons) AS rtot_mpg
  FROM ( SELECT @s_rownum := @s_rownum + 1 AS rownum
              , s.date
              , s.miles
              , s.gallons
           FROM mytable s
           JOIN (SELECT @s_rownum := 0) c
          ORDER BY s.date
       ) q
  JOIN ( SELECT @t_rownum := @t_rownum + 1 AS rownum
              , t.date                  
              , t.miles
              , t.gallons
           FROM mytable t
           JOIN (SELECT @t_rownum := 0) d
          ORDER BY t.date
       ) r
    ON r.rownum <= q.rownum
   AND r.rownum > q.rownum - 2
 GROUP BY q.rownum
```

Your desired value of "n" to specify how many rows to include in each rollup row is specified in the predicate just before the `GROUP BY` clause. In this example, up to "2" rows in each running total row.

If you specify a value of 1, you will get (basically) the original table returned.

To eliminate any "incomplete" running total rows (consisting of fewer than "n" rows), that value of "n" would need to be specified again, adding:

```
HAVING COUNT(1) >= 2
```

sqlfiddle demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/52420/2

### Followup:

**Q:** I'm trying to understand your SQL statement. Does your solution do a select of twenty rows for each row in the db? In other words, if I have 1000 rows will your statement perform 20000 selects? (I'm worried about performance)...

**A:** You are right to be concerned with performance.

To answer your question, no, this does not perform 20,000 selects for 1,000 rows.

The performance hit comes from the two (essentially identical) inline views (aliased as `q` and `r`). What MySQL does with these (basically) is create temporary MyISAM tables (MySQL calls them "derived tables"), which are basically copies of `mytable`, with an extra column, each row assigned a unique integer value from 1 to the number of rows.

Once the two "derived" tables are created and populated, MySQL runs the outer query, using those two "derived" tables as a row source. Each row from `q`, is matched with up to `n` rows from r, to calculate the "running total" miles and gallons.

For better performance, you could use a column already in the table, rather than having the query assign unique integer values. For example, if the `date` column is unique, then you could calculate "running total" over a certain period of days.

```
SELECT q.date                      AS latest_date
     , SUM(q.miles)/SUM(q.gallons) AS latest_mpg
     , COUNT(1)                    AS cnt_rows
     , MIN(r.date)                 AS earliest_date
     , SUM(r.miles)                AS rtot_miles
     , SUM(r.gallons)              AS rtot_gallons
     , SUM(r.miles)/SUM(r.gallons) AS rtot_mpg
  FROM mytable q
  JOIN mytable r
    ON r.date <= q.date
   AND r.date > q.date + INTERVAL -30 DAY
 GROUP BY q.date
```

(For performance, you would want an appropriate index defined with `date` as a leading column in the index.)

---

For the first query, any predicates included (in the inline view definition queries) to reduce the number of rows returned (for example, return only date values in the past year) would reduce the number of rows to be processed, and would also likely improve performance.

---

Again, to your question about running 20,000 selects for 1,000 rows... a nested loops operation is another way to get the same result set. For a large number of rows, this can exhibit slower performance. (On the other hand, this approach can be fairly efficient, when only a few rows are being returned:

```
SELECT q.date                 AS latest_date
     , q.miles/q.gallons      AS latest_mpg
     , ( SELECT SUM(r.miles)/SUM(r.gallons)
           FROM mytable r
          WHERE r.date <= q.date
            AND r.date >= q.date + INTERVAL -90 DAY
       ) AS rtot_mpg
  FROM mytable q
 ORDER BY q.date
```

Comment: I'm trying to understand your SQL statement.  Does your solution do a select of twenty rows for each row in the db?  In other words, if I have 1000 rows will your statement perform 20000 selects?  (I'm worried about performance)...

Comment: I'm wondering if a LIMIT N statement in the joins would reduce the load on the sql server?  (Not sure how, just thinking out load)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT Date, Miles, Gallons, Miles/Gallons as MilesPerGallon,
  @Miles:=@Miles+Miles overallMiles,
  @Gallons:=@Gallons+Gallons overallGallons,
  @RunningTotal:=@Miles/@Gallons runningTotal
FROM YourTable
  JOIN (SELECT @Miles:= 0) t
  JOIN (SELECT @Gallons:= 0) s
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bc88/1)

Which produces the following:

```
DATE                MILES    GALLONS    MILESPERGALLON   RUNNINGTOTAL
January, 25 1993    20       3          6.666667         6.666666666667
February, 07 1993   55.2     7.22       7.645429         7.358121330724
March, 11 1993      44.1     6.28       7.022293         7.230303030303
```

--EDIT--

In response to the comment, you can add another Row Number to limit your results to the last N rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT Date, Miles, Gallons, Miles/Gallons as MilesPerGallon,
    @Miles:=@Miles+Miles overallmiles,
    @Gallons:=@Gallons+Gallons overallGallons,
    @RunningTotal:=@Miles/@Gallons runningTotal,
    @RowNumber:=@RowNumber+1 rowNumber
  FROM (SELECT * FROM YourTable ORDER BY Date DESC) u
    JOIN (SELECT @Miles:= 0) t
    JOIN (SELECT @Gallons:= 0) s
    JOIN (SELECT @RowNumber:= 0) r
  ) t
WHERE rowNumber <= 3
```

Just change your ORDER BY clause accordingly.  And here is the [updated fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bc88/5).

Comment: What limits the RunningTotal to the last N records?

Comment: @Michelle -- I added a RowNumber so you could limit to the last N Records -- Best of luck!

Comment: This stops after 3 rows.  I want the SQL to output all 1000 rows, with the running average of the last 3 (or N).  Otherwise the output looks right.

Comment: @Michelle -- sorry, misunderstood your question :)  Looks like you have an accepted answer so I assume you're good.  Best regards.